# Adding task completion listener for Service task

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I have written following Service task parse handler and my requirement is adding task completion handler for a service task. If I use this parse handler for a user task it is working fine. But when I deploy a BPMN (my server run this parse handler), this gives me null pointer exceptions as there is no taskdefinition for service tasks.

```
(TaskDefinition) bpmnParse.getCurrentActivity().getProperty("taskDefinition")
```

What is the correct way of doing this ?

```
public class MyServiceTaskParseHandler extends AbstractBpmnParseHandler {

private static final Log log = 

LogFactory.getLog(ServiceTskParseHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends BaseElement> getHandledType() {return ServiceTask.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeParse(BpmnParse bpmnParse, BaseElement element) {

        TaskDefinition taskDefinition = (TaskDefinition) bpmnParse.getCurrentActivity().getProperty("taskDefinition");

        // We have to check if data publishing listener has already been associated at server startup
        TaskListener taskCompletionListener = null;
        List<TaskListener> completionListeners = taskDefinition.getTaskListener(TaskListener.EVENTNAME_COMPLETE);
        if (completionListeners != null) {
            for (TaskListener listener : completionListeners) {
                if (listener instanceof TaskCompletionListener) {
                    taskCompletionListener = listener;
                }
            }
        }
        if (taskCompletionListener == null) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Adding data publishing listener to task: " + taskDefinition.getKey());
            }
            taskDefinition.addTaskListener(TaskListener.EVENTNAME_COMPLETE, new TaskCompletionListener());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the default service Task Parse handler used for mail, camel, mule and shell swrvice tasks.

modules/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/bpmn/parser/handler/ServiceTaskParseHandler.java

This should point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps,
Greg